# HTML pages not working after added to Cordova 1.6.0 iOS

Tags: ios, cordova

I have installed Cordova 1.6.0 in xcode 4.x. I have created a new PhoneGap project and executed the same in 5.1.1 iPhone simulator. It was successful saying Cordova is working.
I added the www folder in my project. Now I added my HTML, CSS and JS files in the www folder. I changed the AppDelegate.m and pointed the loading html page to be my login.html. The page loads but without any JS or CSS in it. The login.html contains code like,

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login</title>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta charset="utf-8">    

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/cordova-1.6.0.js"></script>


<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="css/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"
    src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.toastmessage-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"
    src="js/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/json2.js"></script>


<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/jquery.toastmessage-min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css">
```

The page refers all locally stored files. The page also hits an external url to get data in document.ready.
Can anyone please find what is going wrong?

Comment: Where is cordova 1.6.0.js file?

Comment: Sorry @Coder_sLaY, here is the right code.

Comment: have u put the new cordova.plist,MainViewController and AppDelegate files into your Xcode project

Comment: AppDelegate.m and myproject-plist is already present when I create the a phonegap project in xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link helped me.
[Jquery mobile with phonegap is not styling properly for mobile app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10016725/jquery-mobile-with-phonegap-is-not-styling-properly-for-mobile-app)

I was using jquery 1.6.4 which is a wrong combination.
The combination should be-
cordova-1.6.0.js
jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css
jQuery Core 1.7.2
jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js